# Can you add an array of data to a VideoClip array in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I dont even know if I am asking the right question here. Basically, I am trying to load a local file with a bunch of videos to the videoplayer component on unity that then plays them all in order.

I can obtain the data to a string array using directory.getfiles but I dont know how to then use that data to build an array of videoclips to play on the application.

The code I have got is just getting the files and printing them out to the console.

string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Anthony/Desktop/VReditor40221587/Videos/");
        Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", files));

Comment: I think your issue is one of Terminology. This is not a "array of Data". This is a "array of paths". And you are not turning it into a "Video Clip", but a "Playlist of Videos". Combing a bunch of seperate videos or still images into a single video is actually a mater of Video re-encoding.

Comment: Sorry yeh I guess youre right. I was using a VideoClip array originally and just dragging and dropping files into it on the inspector. But i realised on build this wouldnt work, so I needed a folder that my app could access, take all the video files in there and play them on the application. I guess Im just abit stumped with it.

Comment: What part has you lost? How to get the Videos into the Output folder during development? How to get them into their folders during instalaltion?

Comment: The part I am stuck with is trying to get the files from the folder to play on the application. So basically I get the files and print them to the console using the Directory.Getfiles and add it to a string array which I've called files. But after that stage I do not know how to then get those files onto the videoplayer component.

Comment: The unity videoplayer seems to lack a built in playlist feature. But a short searched and I found stuff like this: https://gist.github.com/radiatoryang/95a9865992a78b33d3099f595863eb7f It seems to use 2 cameras (?)  - one to play the current, one to preaload the next video.

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for the help.